# (Android / Java) How do you assign a string and share across activities or java classes?

Tags: java, android

For example's sake, say I just have one button. With XML like this:

> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/PandR"
>     android:id="@+id/PandRA">
> ```

What I want to do in Java, is make a string value that can be accessed on another activity or Java class. Here is what my Java currently looks like:

> public class TeamAOffense extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_aoffense);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Team A's turn.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Make a method that saves a value for pressing PandRA, later used in CalcForAOffBDef

    // Button for PandRA, assigning value for calculating.
    final Button pandrBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PandRA);

    pandrBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // Needs to save value that is later compared.

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TeamAOffense.this, ExchangeAToB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // Button for MandFA, assigning value for calculating.
    final Button mandfBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MandFA);

    mandfBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Needs to save value that is later compared.
            Intent intent = new Intent(TeamAOffense.this, ExchangeAToB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // Button for SandCA, assigning value for calculating.
    final Button sandcBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SandCA);

    sandcBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Needs to save value that is later compared.
            Intent intent = new Intent(TeamAOffense.this, ExchangeAToB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways :

1. To use `Intent.putExtra(String key, String value)`
2. To use `singleton` to pass `Objects` or `String` or even a `custom class`

**Examples**:
Example 1

```
 Intent intent =  new Intent(TeamAOffense.this, ExchangeAToB.class);
 intent.putExtra("KEY", "Value");
 startActivity(intent);
 // and in `ExchangeAToB` class use 
 String key getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY");`
```

Example 2

```
public class MyInstance{
private static MyInstance instance = null;
private Object mObject;
private MyInstance(){
mObject = new Object();
}

public static MyInstance getInstance(){
if(instance == null){
instance = new MyInstance();
}
return instance;
}

public Object getObject(){
return mObject;
}

public void setObject(Object obj){
mObject = obj;
}
}
// Use MyInstance.getInstance().setObject(new String()); // in activity 1
// and Object myObject = MyInstance.getInstance().getObject(); // in activity 2
```

** Don't forget to clear the object after using it